# R: assigning value based on row names

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), B = c(1, 1, 1, 3), C = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), D = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), E = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), F = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), G = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), H = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), row.names = c("month1", "month6", 
"month12", "month24"), class = "data.frame")
> dat
        A B C D E F G H
month1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
month6  1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2
month12 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
month24 1 3 1 1 1 1 2 1
```

Suppose my data looks something like this. I want to assign a value to each of these 8 columns based on when a value > 1 first occurs. If a value > 1 occurs at month 1, I will assign a value of 1 to that column. At month 6, I will assign a value of 1.5 to that column. At month 12, I will assign 2, and at month 24, I will assign 3.

For columns which contain all 1s, I assign `NA` to them. I would like my output to look like

```
 A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
NA   3  NA 1.5  NA  NA 1.5 1.5
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Also, you might consider using tags for your question.

Comment: `sapply(dat,function(x) { which(x > 1)[1L] })` this assigns the value based on row index...but Im not sure how to make it take row names into account instead

Comment: Are you using the earliest month to assign the values, ie. suppose if there are 2 or 3 months have >1, I guess this will assign it to the earliest month where it first occured, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col`.  We convert the data.frame to a logical matrix ('m1'), transpose it ('m1'), get the maximum value column index for each row by using `max.col` with `ties.method='first'`(in case there are multiple TRUE per row), change the `all` FALSE elements in a row to `NA` (using `rowSums` and `NA^`).  Now, we can convert the 'i1' to 'factor', specify the `levels' and` labels', and change it to `numeric`.

```
m1 <- t(dat >1)
i1 <- max.col(m1, 'first') * NA^(!rowSums(m1))
as.numeric(as.character(factor(i1, levels= 1:4, labels=c(1, 1.5, 2,3))))
#[1]  NA 3.0  NA 1.5  NA  NA 1.5 1.5
```

###Update

If there are rows/columns missing in some of the datasets, for e.g., here I am creating a new dataset with 2nd row missing ('dat1') (In case there are multiple datasets, we can place it in a `list` and do this in a loop (`lapply(..`) instead of repeating the steps).  We create a 0 matrix ('m2') with the dimensions and dimnames that have all the rows/columns, replace the 0's in 'm2' with the row/column values that are present in the dataset, and then do the steps as before.

```
dat1 <- dat[-2,]
lst <- list(dat, dat1)
nC1 <- max(sapply(lst, ncol))
nR1 <- max(sapply(lst, nrow))

m2 <- matrix(0, ncol=nC1, nrow=nR1, dimnames=list(paste0('month', 
        c(1,6, 12,24)), LETTERS[1:8]))
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
          m2[rownames(x), colnames(x)] <- as.matrix(x)
         m2  })
lapply(lst1, function(x) {m1 <- t(x >1)
         i1 <- max.col(m1, 'first') * NA^(!rowSums(m1))
  as.numeric(as.character(factor(i1, levels= 1:4, labels=c(1, 1.5, 2,3))))
 })
# [[1]]
# [1]  NA 3.0  NA 1.5  NA  NA 1.5 1.5

# [[2]]
# [1] NA  3 NA NA NA NA  3 NA
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have many different `data.frames` that have different `row.names`? For example some of my `data.frames` don't have the month24 row. Others are missing the month1 row. Is there a way to generalize this so that the value assigned depends on the `row.names`?

Comment: @Adrian Do you have a list of data.frames?

Comment: I do not have a list of data.frames.

Comment: @Adrian In case you have multiple datasets, keep it in a `list` and then we can do this without repeating for each dataset

Comment: @Adrian I updated for possible row/column missing cases.